# Entity Framework Code First with non-user instance

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

these are my first steps with Entity Framework Code First workflow, so maybe I am missing something simple. I created my context class inheriting from DbContext

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

And I executing it in a controller code:

```
var author = new Author()
{
  FirstName = "Julia",
  LastName = "Lerman"
};

using (var context = new Context())
{
  context.Authors.Add(author);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have no other code or configuration that i set for EF. 
When I start the application and hit code in controller everything works fine, the only problem is that database is actually not created in SQL Server but it runs, somewhat, locally. That means I cannot really use SQL Server management studio to inspect the data when my application runs, which I want to do.

I figured out that in web.config automatically folowing key was added:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=false;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

How can I modify this config key (or is there anything else that I need to do) to make sure that this database will run on actual SQL Server express rather than in-process?

Comment: do you have a connection string for your db server?

Comment: It was worth a try. I replaced the connection string with proper connection string to empty database, but it is completely ignored and app runs as it used to. Looks like it is not even used runtime. If I then change name of context class, I can see that new set of files is created in App_Data directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out, thanks to "Programming Entity Framework: Code First" book, apparently it is the convention over configuration scenario, for the query string to be picked up the name of it needs to match the name of the Context class (the one you inherit from DbContext). 
Therefore I need to add new connection string like below:

```
<add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=.\SS2012EXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HomeLibrary;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Original connection string can stay as it is, it is not used run-time. I am not entirely sure what is the purpose of it.

Comment: The DbContext has an overload that accepts a connection string, so you don't have to use the default connection string that it expects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: Also, `ApplicationServices` is used by the built-in Membership/Roles/Profile providers, though I don't recommend relying on them.

Comment: That's correct - I actually prefer to have it in web.config just was not aware that you have to name it based on the name of your class

Comment: Just use `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name of your connection string"]` to use a specific connection string.

Comment: @TiesonT - OMG, you just enlightened me, I totally missed the fact that ApplicationServices is a MVC web.config key, it was added automatically by MVC wizard, not because of EF as I assumed. I opened a while ago a separate question to ask about ApplicationServices key, please reply to it, and I'll accept your answer.